# Python Composite Class JSON Serialization

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have what I would term a composite class

Whereby the class LegoSet is constructed from an instantiation of the class LegoSetVariant and inturn the class LegoSetVariant is constructed from a number of different class instantiations.

This is fine and I can successfully initialize the class. However, I then want to serialize the class object into JSON. This is proving a bit tricky as the composite classes are erroring as non-serializable.

```
class LegoSet:
    def __init__(
        self,
        typename,
        id,
        productCode,
        name,
        slug,
        primaryImage,
        baseImgUrl,
        overrideUrl,
        variant,
    ):
        self.__typename = typename
        self.__id = id
        self.__productCode = productCode
        self.__name = name
        self.__slug = slug
        self.__primaryImage = primaryImage
        self.__baseImgUrl = baseImgUrl
        self.__overrideUrl = overrideUrl
        self.__variant = variant


class LegoSetVariant:
    def __init__(self, id, sku, salePercentage, attributes, price, listPrice):
        self.__id = id
        self.__sku = sku
        self.__salePercentage = salePercentage
        self.__atributes = attributes
        self.__price = price
        self.__listPrice = listPrice


class LegoSetVariantAttributes:
    def __init__(
        self,
        rating,
        maxOrderQuantity,
        availabilityStatus,
        availabilityText,
        vipAvailabilityStatus,
        vipAvailabilityText,
        canAddToBag,
        canAddToWishlist,
        vipCanAddToBag,
        onSale,
        isNew,
        featuredFlags,
    ):
        self.__rating = rating
        self.__maxOrderQuantity = maxOrderQuantity
        self.__availabilityStatus = availabilityStatus
        self.__availabilityText = availabilityText
        self.__vipAvailabilityStatus = vipAvailabilityStatus
        self.__vipAvailabilityText = vipAvailabilityText
        self.__canAddToBag = canAddToBag
        self.__canAddToWishlist = canAddToWishlist
        self.__vipCanAddToBag = vipCanAddToBag
        self.__onSale = onSale
        self.__isNew = isNew
        self.__featuredFlags = featuredFlags


class LegoSetVariantAttributesFeaturedFlags:
    def __init__(self, key, label):
        self.__key = key
        self.__label = label


class LegoSetVariantPrice:
    def __init__(self, formattedAmount, centAmount, currencyCode, formattedValue):
        self.__formattedAmount = formattedAmount
        self.__centAmount = centAmount
        self.__currencyCode = currencyCode
        self.__formattedValue = formattedValue


class LegoSetVariantListPrice:
    def __init__(self, formattedAmount, centAmount):
        self.__formattedAmount = formattedAmount
        self.__centAmount = centAmount
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an object you want to serialize (How  did you construct the object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def unpack_into_dict(object):
    res = {}
    for key, val in object.__dict__.items():
        if hasattr(val, '__dict__'):
            res[key] = unpack_into_dict(val)
        else:
            res[key] = val
    return res
```